# What is the difference of the three variable of Scala's map function

Tags: scala

The following three `map` function call on a Scala `List` all produced the same result.

Can someone tell me what is the actual different on them?

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

l.map(x => x * 2)
l.map{x => x * 2}
l.map{case x => x * 2}
```

Comment: there is no difference. You can also write it as `l.map(_*2)` or `l.map { _ * 2 }` or `l map { _ * 2 }` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to know what role the "case" plays here. How it differs from the "case" in pattern matching.

Comment: @KZhang its the same, you are actually doing pattern matching there with the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` thingy is actually syntax for `PartialFunction`. You can have more than one clause like that:

```
 l.map { 
   case 1 => "one"
   case 2 => "two"
   case _ => "foo"
 }
```

This actually passes a `PartialFunction` to `map`, not just a `Function`, but that works, because `PartialFunction` is a subclass of `Function`. 
The resulting `PartialFunction` is defined on those parameters, that are matched by  a `case` clause, and not on others:

```
l.collect { 
   case 1 => "one"
   case 2 => "two"
}
```

Returns `List("one", "two")`

You can also use `case` to deconstruct tuples or case classes (or anything else that has `unapply` or `unapplySeq`), like pointed out in the other answer, same way you would in a `match` expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
l.map{case x => x * 2}
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
l.map(input => input match { case x => x * 2 })
```

Which means - we use pattern matching (with a single case) on the input argument of the anonymous function passed to `map`.

Obviously, in this case, the pattern matching doesn't do much (matches everything, and no "unapplying" takes place), but one can easily see how this could be useful in other occasions, for example to "break up" tuples:

```
val l: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq((1, 2), (3, 4))
l.map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```